# Datatable not returning records in .net

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, datatable

[image]

[image]

> 

**The `datatable` shows no rows**

[image]

My query is correct , However no records are coming in the `Datatable` Don't know what is wrong

Please help

Comment: Make sure you are checking the table after Fill() is executed

Comment: it shows no rows even if i execute the fill command

Comment: Show your open connection method and connection string. Check whether you are connected to correct database (if multiple databases available in development environment).

Comment: @Prasanna open/close connection method it'not necessary,Fill Methode do this issuse(Open/Close) automatically.

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi I just needed to check whether he is connected to correct database

Comment: it is connected to the correct database

Comment: @Prasanna when he connects to anothor database he gets Expecption like this : "Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'user'."

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi. You are correct! But my intention was, i have seen that most of developers get confused when have multiple instances of the same database in development environments. Acoording to vini's response here it is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with your communication with Sql Server. Here are some things to check:

1) That the exact same query returns results when run in SQL

2) The Sql Connection string you are running is not set to use a default schema different than the one that view is in.

3) The view does not return more than 1 dataset and/or table (filling a datatable directly will just take the first table in a dataset.

4) You are checking the data table after .Fill() is being executed and not before.

Please update us if that narrows your problem. Otherwise you're going to have to post your OpenConnection code and your Sql view syntax.

Comment: 1. one thing the connection is open when i run this query i have checked that
2. This query runs in sql server perfectly

Comment: Your edit makes no difference. If you're going to inspect "dt" you need to wait until the line AFTER the .Fill command.

Comment: DataTable donot view you any thing until you use _foreach (datacoloumn in dt) or DataRow_

Answer (score 0):

try use this code :

```
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string strsql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql,con);
                da.Fill(dt);
            } catch { }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in web.config

```
    <appSettings> 
<add key="con" value="data source="servername";uid="username";pwd="password";initial catalog="databasename"></add> 
</appSettings>
```

.aspx page

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringA"].ToString()); 
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string strsql)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql,con);
                da.Fill(dt);

                if(dt!=null && dt.rows.Count>0)
                {
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```